# How can I delete an unnecessary row from an array without error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "label")?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-native

[Delete row image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtwC0.png)

I need to delete the last row from my optionsThree array so that i have only one element displayed from optionsThree like in the picture.But if i delete the unnecesary element and have left only one element, than i get this error - "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "label")"
**Also after added the second for loop i got an error - Encountered two children with the same key.**
Maybe there is a better structure to make the layout as in the picture?

```
const rows: JSX.Element[] = [];

for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1) {
    const option1 = options[i];
    const option2 = optionsTwo[i];

    rows.push(
        <View key={i}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Radio
                    onPress={() => onChange(option1.value)}
                    label={option1.label}
                    checked={option1.value === value}
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                />

                <Radio
                    onPress={() => onChange(option2.value)}
                    label={option2.label}
                    checked={option2.value === value}
                    style={{ flex: 1}}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1) {
    const option3 = optionsThree[i];

    rows.push(
        <View key={i}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Radio
                    onPress={() => onChange(option3.value)}
                    label={option3.label}
                    checked={option3.value === value}
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                />
                <View style={{ flex: 1}} />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
return (
    <View>
        <View>{rows}</View>
    </View>
);
}
```

My option arrays

```
               options={[
                        { label: "label", value: "value" },
                        { label: "label", value: "value3" },
                    ]}
                    optionsTwo={[
                        { label: "label", value: "value2" },
                        { label: "label", value: "value4" },
                        { label: "label", value: "value7" },
                    ]}
                    optionsThree={[
                        { label: "label", value: "value11" },
                        { label: "label", value: "value12" },//should delete this
                    ]}
```

Comment: Can you include the imports too, i am trying to solve and want to see the packages you are using for the radio btn.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is because you are using `options.length` to iterate `optionsThree`, it should be something like

```
for (let i = 0; i < optionsThree.length; i += 1)
```

But also it is an issue in the first loop, because it is no taking into account the last item of `optionsTwo`, and, if `options` has more items than `optionsTwo` you will get again the same error.